# How to run a workflow after login?

Tags: macos, login

I want to make the following workflow run after login.

What is the best way to execute this workflow when someone logs in to the Mac

Because if the IP range is start in `172.19` represents I'm in my office.

Check the NIC `en4`

### PSEDUO CODE

```
CHECK CURRENT IP, if it starts with 172.19 then do the following actions # 
mkdir /Volumes/tmp
mount_smbfs -N "smb://guest@192.168.14.6/QMD"  /Volumes/tmp
```

Comment: So you want to know how to mount a specific volume at login, but only if connected to a certain network?

Comment: There's not quite enough information here to answer this. Specifically: *which* interface needs to have an IP address in that range? Is it always the same interface? Does this need to run just for your or for any random user who might log in to the machine? What should happen if something is mounted there already?

Comment: It looks you asking two questions here. How to Auto run code after login and how to write code that will check the IP. You need to ask one question  here. Then ask the other question on another question thread.

Comment: Does it need to be running *via Alfred* or are other means ok as well?

Comment: @patrix , no not neccessary